# Not getting the prompt for "Post on your behalf" in Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iOS application in which there is Facebook login and sharing of contents on user's wall from the app.
Now,at the time of login I have provided the "publish_actions" permission but when i redirected to the Safari browser I am getting prompt for Facebook about "YourApp will receive the following info:your public profile".

Here,why I am not getting the prompt like "YourApp may post on your behalf"?

Note:Is this related to the Facebook app submission for reviewing for extended permission(As I have not submitted the app for review yet.)?

After submission of app I will be able to get the prompt of post on your behalf?

I am using    openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions method for this.

Comment: Your app cannot get permission "publish_actions"(write permission) at the time of  login. After login while publishing you should call for "publish_actions" permission.

Comment: @Ritu I am using [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos".., method for publishing content but how can i give publish_actions permission here with FBRequestConnection?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the url:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#adding

Apps should separate the request of read and publish permissions.
Use the following code with FBSession:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"] defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceEveryone allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        if(!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
            //Share
            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"..,
        }           
        else{
            //error
        }
    }];
```

Comment: I used your code but now I am getting error.Please see the screen shot here: http://imgur.com/FhBIsnq

Comment: That message mentions the permission `publish_stream`, which doesn’t exist any more. Ritu use `publish_actions` in the code sample shown …

Comment: Are you using "publish_stream" anywhere. It has been deprecated.

Comment: @Ritu no I am using publish_actions permission not publish_stream